# Trigger on Account Name Init caps

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update, list, update

I have a requirement to make First Name , Middle Name and Last Name fields as initial caps and then form the Name field by concatenating them. Can someone suggest a way out?Please find my trigger here. Sorry for late update. getting below error.

Compile Error: Variable l is used before it is declared. at line 6 column 1

Trigger:

```
trigger ACCOUNT_AFTER_INSUPD_NAME on Account (after insert , after update) {

  List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
  acc = [SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Middle_vod__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN: Trigger.oldMap.keySet() LIMIT 1];
  for(Account a: acc) {
    String f = a.FirstName;
    List<String> FName= f.split(' ');
    for(Integer i=0;i<FName.size();i++) {
      FName[i] = (FName[i].substring(0,1)).toUppercase() +(FName[i].substring(1,FName[i].length()));
      a.FirstName=a.FirstName+' '+FName[i];
    }

    String m = a.Middle_vod__c;
    List<String> MName= m.split(' ');
    for(Integer i=0;i<MName.size();i++) {
      MName[i] = (MName[i].substring(0,1)).toUppercase() +(MName[i].substring(1,MName[i].length()));
      a.Middle_vod__c=a.Middle_vod__c+' '+MName[i];
    }

    String l = a.LastName;
    List<String> LName= l.split(' ');
    for(Integer i=0;i<LName.size();i++) {
      LName[i] = (LName[i].substring(0,1)).toUppercase() +(LName[i].substring(1,FName[i].length()));
      a.LastName=a.LastName+' '+LName[i];
    }
  }
  update acc;
}
```

Comment: Are these custom fields on Account?

Comment: Yes keith. Sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: Do you want to convert User Data in this format or do you want to enforce User to enter data in this format?

Comment: No I want User to enter what he likes. Then I need to incorporate this logic in an after update , after insert Trigger that will do the Need ful changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try out something like :

```
String fName = Acc.FirstName__c.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+ Acc.FirstName__c.substring(1,Acc.FirstName__c.length()).
```

Replace FirstName__c with appropriate API name in your code. (Acc is your Account instance for a FOR loop)

thanks,

Comment: Hi Amit!! I have put my trigger here. Can you please help me here? Thanks, yes I was using the same logic.

Comment: Sorry for a silly mistake in my code. I have updated my code. It works for me.